# Bing Maps Distance Matrix API error : 'content: This parameter is missing or invalid.'

Tags: python, python-requests, bing-maps

I was trying the examples of how to use Bing's Maps Distance Matrix API.
The example was taken "as is" from their website ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/examples/distance-matrix-example)).

Both the get and post examples fail with the following errors :

```
{'authenticationResultCode': 'ValidCredentials',
 'brandLogoUri': 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png',
 'copyright': 'Copyright © 2020 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.',
 'errorDetails': ['One or more parameters are not valid.',
  'content: This parameter is missing or invalid.'],
 'resourceSets': [],
 'statusCode': 400,
 'statusDescription': 'Bad Request',
 'traceId': '338104f79bff4dfe9b18d0333e80abe7|DU00000D6A|0.0.0.0'}
```

and

```
{'authenticationResultCode': 'ValidCredentials',
 'brandLogoUri': 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png',
 'copyright': 'Copyright © 2020 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.',
 'errorDetails': ['JSON input is incorrect'],
 'resourceSets': [],
 'statusCode': 400,
 'statusDescription': 'Bad Request',
 'traceId': 'cbef56289d164cc1a691ad8f328e4cf3|DU00000B71|0.0.0.0'}
```

The requests are made in Python with 'requests' library. Here is an example of invocation for  the get request :

```
url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=47.6044,-122.3345;47.6731,-122.1185;47.6149,-122.1936&destinations=45.5347,-122.6231;47.4747,-122.2057&travelMode=driving&key={myKeyHere}"
r = req.post(url)
j = r.json()
```

and this is the post request :

```
url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?key={myKeyHereWithNoBrackets}"
headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
}
payload ={
    "origins": [{
        "latitude": 47.6044,
        "longitude": -122.3345
    },
    {
        "latitude": 47.6731,
        "longitude": -122.1185
    },
    {
        "latitude": 47.6149,
        "longitude": -122.1936
    }],
    "destinations": [{
        "latitude": 45.5347,
        "longitude": -122.6231
    }, 
    {
        "latitude": 47.4747,
        "longitude": -122.2057
    }],
    "travelMode": "driving"
}
response = req.post(url,headers=headers, data=payload)
json_obj = response.json()
json_obj
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it. When making a POST request with `content-type:application/json` we must convert the payload to json. In order to do so I've modified the following line :

```
response = req.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

to the following :

```
response = req.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Indeed I must also import the json library.

For the GET request I'm still unsure what to do. If someone knows please comment to updated the response or post a response of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar issue. Even posted a similar question a few hours back. The following code is working for the post request for a single source to single destination.

```
import requests
import json

payload = {
    "origins": [{"latitude": 26.488991, "longitude": 80.263585}],
    "destinations": [{"latitude": 26.761714, "longitude": 80.885623}],
    "travelMode": "driving",
}

paramtr = {"key": "YOUR_KEY_GOES_HERE"}

r = requests.post('https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix', data = 
json.dumps(payload), params = paramtr)

print(r.json())
```

The following was the response

```
{'authenticationResultCode': 'ValidCredentials',
 'brandLogoUri': 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png',
 'copyright': 'Copyright © 2020 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This 
API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or 
transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft 
Corporation.',
 'resourceSets': [{'estimatedTotal': 1,
   'resources': [{'__type': 
'DistanceMatrix:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
     'destinations': [{'latitude': 26.761714, 'longitude': 80.885623}],
     'errorMessage': 'Request completed.',
     'origins': [{'latitude': 26.488991, 'longitude': 80.263585}],
     'results': [{'destinationIndex': 0,
       'originIndex': 0,
       'totalWalkDuration': 0,
       'travelDistance': 85.961,
       'travelDuration': 80.217}]}]}],
 'statusCode': 200,
 'statusDescription': 'OK',
 'traceId': 'b094c60cdd6e48cbad66e47b85696123|HK00000C14|0.0.0.0|HK00000A3C, 
HK00000882'}
```

I hope it helps. I still do not understand the complete logic behind it. If someone knows please comment. Happy to learn.